# Как сохранить порядок подстрок? (React+PHP)

Tags: php, laravel, reactjs

Задача "Как сохранить порядок отображения подстрок"!

Есть список строк (типа todo лист)
У каждой строки есть подстрока. (в базе они связанные по id)
При клике на подстроку, после нее должна появиться новая.
!!После нее, а не в конце списка.
Такого можно достичь либо splice либо передачей нового списка.
Но вот незадача: в базе список подстрок - это общий список подстрок, всех сразу.
А реакт его уже сортирует визуально (сравнивая по id со строкой)
Вопрос - как же добавлять строку после той, на которую кликнул и при том сохранять позицию.

Comment: Отображение работает примерно так: по списку строк идет цикл, при каждой итерации берется id строки. Далее на этой итерации идет цикл по подстрокам, и если id подстроки совпало - отображает подстроку.
Возможно это крайне тупо, но потому и спрашиваю - как сделать лучше и решить таки эту задачу)

Comment: это вопрос отображения или вопрос выдачи сервера?

то есть это ajax запросы подгружающие подстроки, или весь список (и строки и подстроки) загружаются сразу, а вопрос в том как их отрисовать?

то есть какие данные есть и что с ними нужно сделать и где именно: на сервере или в браузере?